# How to access the hash fragment in the final url after request

Tags: python, url, request, spotify

Whenever I copy and paste the following into a web browser

Original URL

http://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=XXX2d0ff4186b517daa4e1c577e4&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost:5000&scope=playlist-modify-public%20playlist-modify-private&response_type=token

I get this for the final url

Final URL

http://localhost:5000/#access_token=XXX-LQY7xCQXTqpmsfroChl5yeUoiIDmoBfybqc9psLE2WFwP2UNQ26nVuiLGQkIWA-4occeXbrScaO5mqmMHZpgDPjTcSEfN9VZCLKKyfE46FUsucmCetP9owY_bRWoraZ8P2wwq0osZEMit0jmOrThvPTyKqp7O_rAbwT1BUsLeB9ux7xdLnTreocpmtZl3wqMXz24B2mwRMEieb_Dq2PUgIaK3zE7X-RvnzqQ&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600

My question is how to get the access_token in the final url by using the original URL programmatically.  Preferably in python.  The original URL will be constant so I won't need to make any changes to the values of the parameters that I already declared

I have already tried

- Using python requests, and viewing the response.url.(both using POST and GET)  But when I do it only shows the original url.
- Same concept using urllib
- Displaying it with .json, json(), .text, .headers, and pretty much all of the request functions available, but again it only makes references to the original url.

Comment: You can't, the fragment is not transmitted by the browser. It looks like you have at some point selected the wrong OAuth2 flow type.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes I chose the implicit grant method because I was struggling to get a valid access_token when using both other flows.  I was receiving a access_token but it was way shorter than the correct one I was getting using this method

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the grant flow that you are using is [Implicit Grant](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow) which is used to obtain user's token. However, using this flow requires user's interaction via browser to complete the flow and get the token.

That means [Implicit Grant](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow) can't be used to obtain user's access token via browserless application without user's interaction.

In case of browserless application, the authentication flow that you might want to use is [Client Credential](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow) flow that you can get the access token directly in the response. The limitation of this grant flow is that you can't use the endpoint that requires user's identity.

In the FAQ section of [the document](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/) might have an answer for your scenario that you might consider a refresh token instead.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the browser contains a valid session with the identity provider (authorize url -> callback url), but your programmatic way does not (authorize url ->  authorize url).

Assuming it is implicit grant, and the aim is to retrieve the access token which is in the url hash fragment. The scripting would need to login to the identity provider or have the relevant session cookies/data.

Sample Python Code:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlparse

singleSession = requests.Session()

# start with original url as https://oauth-abc.def.com/auth?client_id=123&redirect_uri=https://abc.def.com/oauth-callback&response_type=token&nonce=123&scope=something
# since there is no session with identity provider, the following get request should lead to redirect to identity provider / third party login form page. 
url_login_authorize = 'https://oauth-abc.def.com/auth?client_id=123&redirect_uri=https://abc.def.com/oauth-callback&response_type=token&nonce=123&scope=something'
result_login_oauth_page = singleSession.get(url_login_authorize, allow_redirects=True)

# result_login_oauth_page.url is the identity provider login form html page url which could be unique
# post credentials to authenticate with identity provider
url_login_oauth_endpoint = result_login_oauth_page.url + '/login'
result_login_oauth = singleSession.post(url_login_oauth_endpoint, credentials_object, allow_redirects=True) 

# post request to grant/confirm the requested scopes with authenticated session
url_login_confirm_oauth_endpoint = result_login_oauth_page.url + '/confirm'
result_login_confirm_oauth = singleSession.post(url_login_confirm_oauth_endpoint, {}, allow_redirects=True) 

# end with the final url as https://abc.def.com/oauth-callback#access_token=ilovemoney&expires_in=3600&token_type=Bearer&scope=something
result_oauth_callback_parse = urlparse(result_login_confirm_oauth.url)
result_oauth_callback_params = dict()
for callback_param in result_oauth_callback_parse.fragment.split("&"): 
    callback_param_split = callback_param.split("=")
    result_oauth_callback_params[callback_param_split[0]] = callback_param_split[1]
    
print("result_oauth_callback_params['access_token']: ", result_oauth_callback_params['access_token'])
```